# Can Half-Orc choose Alternate Racial Traits?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, racial-traits, half-orc

So, according to the [official FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qf9):

> half-orcs may select racial favored class options, archetypes, traits, and so on, as if they were a full member of both races

Does this mean that I also can select Alternate Racial Traits like *Dual Talent* or *Eye for Talent*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Alternate racial traits aren't [traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits)

Alternate racial traits such as those listed in the descriptions of [half-orcs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/half-orc) and [humans](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/human) (for example, acute darkvision and adoptive parentage, respectively) are specific and unique to those races and different from the [traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits) the GM usually allows a character to get two of.

Some of those [traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits) are [race traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits), usually restricted to certain races. The [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qf9) is clarifying that, for example, a half-orc can pick half-orc and human race traits (although usually only one race trait per category can usually be selected; see [Restrictions on Trait Selection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits#TOC-Restrictions-on-Trait-Selection)). For example, a half-orc can pick the trait [Almost Human](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/almost-human) (a half-orc racial trait) or [Aspiring Bard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/aspiring-bard-human) (a human racial trait).

(Just in case, note that a member of a race *only* has available its race's racial traits to replace with alternate racial traits. That means, for example, a [half-orc](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/half-orc) can't replace the [human](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/human) racial trait bonus feat with the alternate racial trait adoptive parentage because the half-orc *just doesn't have* the racial trait bonus feat. The FAQ's *and so on* could mean that were a racial trait *shared* by members of the half-*whatever* and *whatever* race, such a racial trait could possibly be replaced with an alternate racial trait that replaced such a racial trait from *either* the half-*whatever* side *or* the *whatever* side, but the GM must decide if the FAQ is, in fact, being *that* inclusive. Also, as of this writing, no such shared trait exists.)